# CoreWLAN in swift

Tags: ios, swift, corewlan

I want to use the `CoreWLAN` in my swift project but when I write `import CoreWLAN` the module is not known.

Is the CoreWLAN existing by default? If not how can I add it in my project?

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 1):

[CoreWLAN](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corewlan) is not available on iOS.

As can been seen on the documentation page, it states SDK macOS.
[image]

Comment: I want know a network name. I found that `CWInterface` can do that and for that I have to import the CoreWLAN. Is there another alternative to get a network name?